# how to use groupby or pivot_table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which i have four columns id,opposition,innings and wickets . I want to group by innings and opposition and want the sum of wicket and count of opposition.

consider this is my dataframe.

[image]

**and my required output of the dataframe should be**

[image]

The wickets column is the sum of wickets group by innings and opposition, and the match_play is the count of opposition group by opposition and innings.

I have tried with pivot table but got  `'Opposition' not 1-dimensional`

```
table = inn.pivot_table(values=['Opposition', 'Wickets'], index=['Opposition', 'Inning_no'],
                    aggfunc=['count','sum'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.groupby()` on a dataframe. And `reset_index()` to convert `Opposition` and `Innings` to normal columns again (they are converted to multiindex during `groupby`)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Opposition':['Sri Lanka', 'Sri Lanka', 'UAE','UAE','Sri Lanka'],
                   'Innings':[1,2,1,2,1], 'Wickets':[13,17,14,18,29]})

t = df.groupby(['Opposition', 'Innings'])['Wickets'].agg(Wickets=('sum'),
                                                         Match_play=('count')).reset_index()
print(t)
```

Output:

```
  Opposition  Innings  Wickets  Match_play
0  Sri Lanka        1       42           2
1  Sri Lanka        2       17           1
2        UAE        1       14           1
3        UAE        2       18           1
```

Comment: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'

Comment: What is your pandas version? (`pip freeze` in terminal and look for pandas)

Comment: I have correct it 

inn.groupby(['Opposition', 'Inning_no'])['Wickets'].agg([('Wickets', 'sum'), ('Opposition', 'count')])

Comment: but the reset_index() not working on this @Mark